# How to disable automatic PERL5LIB setting in CentOS7.4

Tags: linux, perl, centos7

I just installed CentOS 7.4.

All users on the system, regardless of whether they're running /bin/bash or /bin/tcsh, seem to automatically inherit a setting for the PERL5LIB environment variable pointing to `/home/<user>/perl5/lib/perl5`, together with an automatically-created perl5 subdirectory in their home directory.

How can I turn the above system-wide behavior off, so that all users who log in have PERL5LIB unset?

I've searched dot files for each user, system setup files, and all over the web but seem to be missing the secret. I know this is possible since I've managed this before, but have lost the details of the treasure hunt and would appreciate if someone could provide the key hint in a StackOverflow answer.

Comment: Did you check all the files in /etc/profile.d/ ?

Comment: 'grep -i perl5 /etc/profile.d/*' comes up empty

Comment: ...although that may have been on track, /etc/profile.d/perl-homedir.{csh,sh} have PERL_HOMEDIR set to '1'

Comment: That looks promising. Try setting that to 0 and re-login?

Comment: That worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @Chris Turner in comments above. The solution is to modify the two files `/etc/profile.d/perl-homedir.sh` and `/etc/profile.d/perl-homedir.csh`, changing the setting of `PERL_HOMEDIR` from `1` to `0`. After logging out and logging back in, the `PERL5LIB` environment variable is no longer set.

Answer (score 2):

Create a file $HOME/.perl-homedir:

> PERL_HOMEDIR=0

This solution works even **without root privileges**.

---

My system version:

> $ uname -a
>
> Linux login 3.10.0-693.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Aug 22 21:09:27 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux